# T4 Include file path from project root

Tags: .net, t4

How can I include file relatively to project root? Somthing like `<# @include file="~/Infrastructure/Manager.ttinclude" #>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `$(ProjectDir)`

```
<#@ include file="$(ProjectDir)\Infrastructure\Manager.ttinclude" #>
```

You can also use `$(SolutionDir)` for the Solution root.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to solve the problems I was having with trying to share a single library file with T4 templates in multiple projects.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to include file in some shared project then you can use below

```
<#@ include file="..\AnotherProjectFolderName\AnotherSubFolder\Shared.ttinclude" #>
```

First .. will be resolved to current file path
So if .tt is under any sub folder of project directory then you can use

```
<#@ include file="..\..\AnotherProjectDirectory\AnotherSubFolder\Shared.ttinclude" #>
```

One ..\ means one folder level up.