# Entity Framework 6.1 - customize code first generation from existing database by using several *.t4 files

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Is it possible to split the code for customizing the code-first generation into several t4 template files?

After installing the `EntityFramework.CodeTemplates` package, the 2 following T4 files are available: `Context.cs.t4` and `EntityType.cs.t4`.

I could not find any possibility to add from these 2 t4 files references to other external `*.t4` files.

For the "standard" `*.tt` files it is possible to add such lines:

```
...
<#@ include file="MyEFSpecialUtility.CS.ttinclude" #>
...
```

Is this possible with the `Context.cs.t4` and `EntityType.cs.t4` files ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include files. You need to be aware of the pathing issues. You can use something like this:

```
<# @include file="$(ProjectDir)\Infrastructure\T4\MyEFSpecialUtility.CS.ttinclude" #>
```

See here for include description: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-include-directive/

Path issues: [T4 Include file path from project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757730/t4-include-file-path-from-project-root)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the "include file=..." syntax is working for *tt files. But by installing the EntityFramework 6.1 t4 templates for code first from existing database ([EntityFramework.CodeTemplates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/)) you get two template files with the extension *.t4, and they are somehow different from the *.tt template files. I was asking for the syntax to include external template files into the *.t4 template files.

Comment: Those `.t4` files are identical in structure and capability to any `*.tt` files - both file extensions stand for **T4 Template** files